# How to detect that "where i am" in a usercontrol?

Tags: css, menu

I have a user control called "TopMenu". I have five pages in my website. Menu codes are like that below:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UstMenu.ascx.cs"         Inherits="UstMenu" %>
<ul class="tabs menu">
<li>
<a href="Default.aspx" class="active">Anasayfa</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="AboutUs.aspx">Hakkımızda</a>
</li>enter code here
<li>
<a href="Products.aspx">Ürünler</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="Support.aspx">Destek</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="Contact.aspx">İletişim</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have an "active" class as you see upthere in my css.For example, If a user click on support page, Support page link must take "active" class. I dont want to write my menu to all of my pages.    How can i detect which page i am in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on the back end, or on the front end via JS or CSS. If you want to stick with CSS, the trick is to place a different class or ID on each page, say on the `<body>` element:

```
<body class="about">
```

On each list item, you put something similar. E.g.

```
<a class="about" href="AboutUs.aspx">Hakkımızda</a>
```

Then, in your CSS file, have a series of declarations like this:

```
.about .about, .contact .contact, .home .home {active styles here}
```

(As a side note, it's better to call these "current" links rather than "active" ones, as ":active" links are something different.)